# How to write an inline if statement with python executed with -c in a Makefile?

Tags: python, makefile

I am trying to write this small python program to execute with python through the `-c` option:

```
python -c "import sys;if 2==sys.version_info.major: raise RuntimeError('Must use python3')"
```

However, this is raising a syntax error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    import sys;if 2==sys.version_info.major: raise RunTimeError('Must use python3')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

is there a way to write this such that it does work in the above? And if it's invalid, is there a canonical reference to what syntaxes are allowed in `-c` executed code?

I am doing this in a Makefile.

Comment: From which shell? The answer you have will work with bash but not `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in my case it's a Makefile. I'll edit.

Comment: ...yeah, that's a *very* different scenario, and really needs to be part of the title and tagging. (Indeed, it's almost an invalidating-prior-answers level edit, worthy of asking as a separate question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal newlines are perfectly valid inside single-quoted strings in POSIX shells:

```
python -c '
import sys
if 2 == sys.version_info.major:
    raise RuntimeError("Must use python3")
'
```

This means you aren't dependent on having bash, ksh93 or zsh with the `$''` extension.

---

If this is in a Makefile:

```
define python_script
import sys
if 2 == sys.version_info.major:
    raise RuntimeError("Must use python3")
endef

test:
        python -c "$$python_script"
```

Comment: This is what I ended up going with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\n`.

```
python -c "import sys"$'\n'"if 2 == sys.version_info.major:"$'\n'"  raise RuntimeError('Must use python3')"
```

...this assumes you're using `bash` or some closely related shell. But otherwise obviously you can still just have newlines in the string, especially if you're calling `python -c` from a program using `exec` or something.

Comment: `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` on that one.

Comment: @enderland fixt

Comment: `bash-3.2$ python -c "import sys"$'\n'"if 2 == sys.version_info.major:"$'\n'"  raise RuntimeError('Must use python3')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
RuntimeError: Must use python3`